# Do I need to use a caching technology like memcached or redis?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, redis, memcached

I am new to web development in general.
I am developing a social media website (very much like twitter) using django rest framework as backend and react as front end. I am going to deploy the app to Heroku.

Now, I just heard about this thing called memcached and redis. So, what is the usecase here? Should I use it or It's just for high traffic websites?

Comment: Are you using your app for production or is it just for development?

Comment: Yes, It's for production. I am making it for the folks at my university but I hope to expand more in the future

Answer (score 1):

Cache in generally called in-memory cache, which store data primarily in memory(like memcached and Redis), and will provide faster way for data access in heavy traffic case.

And Cache-database consistency is always been an issue as you do have multiple different data sources. There are some good solutions to improve it but it still not perfect in sync.

So based on your read/write traffic, if db can handle the traffic perfectly and no performance issue, you don't need to consider cache(most of the productive database also have caching, like MySQL, or DynamoDB). And if db cannot handle your traffic, you should consider using cache.

Comment: I am usng postgresql

Comment: I haven't made the app yet. I don't know If I need to use it or not.

Comment: Do you mean that I should just build the app now and later on, If I have issues, I could incorporate memcached or I should use it from the beginning

Comment: Yes I think you can build app with db only first as cache is not necessary for now. Also integrate cache with existing app is quite easy in the future.